# Rotating an ImageView within a Layout... how?

Tags: android

I have a layout with an image on it (embedded in an ImageView). I need to rotate the image (let's say) 90 degrees CCW.

I've written code to animate the image rotating...:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    private ImageView mImageView = null;
    private Animation mRotateAnimation = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image);
        mRotateAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.my_rotate_90);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            mImageView.startAnimation(mRotateAnimation);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

The image smoothly rotates 90 degrees, but then snaps back to its original state. This is what the Android documentation says will happen after an animation completes. Presumably, on the notification that the animation has ended, I'm supposed to transform the ImageView (or the underlying drawable), and possibly invalidate it to trigger a redraw.

All well and good, except that **I can't find a way to do it, and I can't find any examples of anyone else doing it**.

I tried using `getImageMatix`/`setImageMatrix` on `mImageView`, with no apparent effect. There are subclasses of Drawable that will rotate an image, but there is no setDrawable() method on ImageView, so I don't see how to use one.

I searched the examples; though a few of them involve animation and rotation (notably LunarLander), none of them are animating an ImageView, and then leaving it in some transformed state.

Surely I'm missing something simple here... aaaargh, how do you rotate an ImageView within a layout?

Thanks.

Comment: I should add that 90 degrees was just a nice round example. Rotations could be any number of degrees, so "make four versions of each image: 0, 90, 180, and 270 degree rotations" isn't going to work as a solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ImageView setImageDrawable will configure the drawable in the Image. This should allow you to use the ImageView class, and thus use the Matrix functions on that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this MultiTouchImageView, it worked fine for me.

```
public class MultiTouchImageView extends ImageView implements OnTouchListener{

float[] lastEvent = null;
float d = 0f;
float newRot = 0f;
public static String fileNAME;
public static int framePos = 0;
//private ImageView view;
private boolean isZoomAndRotate;
private boolean isOutSide;
// We can be in one of these 3 states
private static final int NONE = 0;
private static final int DRAG = 1;
private static final int ZOOM = 2;
private int mode = NONE;

private PointF start = new PointF();
private PointF mid = new PointF();
float oldDist = 1f;
public MultiTouchImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}


public MultiTouchImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}


public MultiTouchImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    //view = (ImageView) v;
    bringToFront();
    // Handle touch events here...
    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        //savedMatrix.set(matrix);
        start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
        mode = DRAG;
        lastEvent = null;
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
        oldDist = spacing(event);
        if (oldDist > 10f) {
            midPoint(mid, event);
            mode = ZOOM;
        }

        lastEvent = new float[4];
        lastEvent[0] = event.getX(0);
        lastEvent[1] = event.getX(1);
        lastEvent[2] = event.getY(0);
        lastEvent[3] = event.getY(1);
        d =  rotation(event);
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        isZoomAndRotate = false;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE:
        isOutSide = true;
        mode = NONE;
        lastEvent = null;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
        mode = NONE;
        lastEvent = null;
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        if(!isOutSide){
            if (mode == DRAG && !isZoomAndRotate) {
                isZoomAndRotate = false;
                setTranslationX((event.getX() - start.x) + getTranslationX());
                setTranslationY((event.getY() - start.y) + getTranslationY());
            } else if (mode == ZOOM && event.getPointerCount() == 2) {
                isZoomAndRotate = true;
                boolean isZoom = false;
                if(!isRotate(event)){
                    float newDist = spacing(event);
                    if (newDist > 10f) {
                        float scale = newDist / oldDist * getScaleX();
                        setScaleX(scale);
                        setScaleY(scale);
                        isZoom = true;
                    }
                }
                else if(!isZoom){
                    newRot = rotation(event);
                    setRotation((float)(getRotation() + (newRot - d)));
                }
            }
        }

        break;
    }
    new GestureDetector(new MyGestureDectore());
    Constants.currentSticker = this;
    return true;
}
private class MyGestureDectore extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener{

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        bringToFront();
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }

}
private float rotation(MotionEvent event) {
    double delta_x = (event.getX(0) - event.getX(1));
    double delta_y = (event.getY(0) - event.getY(1));
    double radians = Math.atan2(delta_y, delta_x);
    return (float) Math.toDegrees(radians);
}
private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
    return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
}

private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
    point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
}

private boolean isRotate(MotionEvent event){
    int dx1 = (int) (event.getX(0) - lastEvent[0]);
    int dy1 = (int) (event.getY(0) - lastEvent[2]);
    int dx2 = (int) (event.getX(1) - lastEvent[1]);
    int dy2 = (int) (event.getY(1) - lastEvent[3]);
    Log.d("dx1 ", ""+ dx1);
    Log.d("dx2 ", "" + dx2);
    Log.d("dy1 ", "" + dy1);
    Log.d("dy2 ", "" + dy2);
    //pointer 1
    if(Math.abs(dx1) > Math.abs(dy1) && Math.abs(dx2) > Math.abs(dy2)) {
        if(dx1 >= 2.0 && dx2 <=  -2.0){
            Log.d("first pointer ", "right");
            return true;
        }
        else if(dx1 <= -2.0 && dx2 >= 2.0){
            Log.d("first pointer ", "left");
            return true;
        }
    }
    else {
         if(dy1 >= 2.0 && dy2 <=  -2.0){
                Log.d("seccond pointer ", "top");
                return true;
            }
            else if(dy1 <= -2.0 && dy2 >= 2.0){
                Log.d("second pointer ", "bottom");
                return true; 
            }

    }

    return false;
}
}
```